# Setting ComboBox.SeletectedItem VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I know this is an easy task, but I'm having trouble setting **ComboBox.SelectedItem**.Let's say i have the following code....

```
Class InnerClass
    Public InnerProperty As String
End Class

Class [Class]
    Public [Property] As String
    Public InnerClass As InnerClass
End Class

Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object,ByVal e as EventArgs)
    Dim cls as New [Class]
    Dim innerCls as New InnerClass
    Dim list as New BindingList(Of InnerClass)

    list.Add(New InnerClass)
    list.Add(New InnerClass)
    list.Add(New InnerClass)       
    cls.InnerClass=list.Items(2)
    ComboBox1.DataSource=list 
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember="InnerProperty"
    ComboBox1.DisplayValue="InnerProperty"
    ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem",cls,"InnerClass") 'always displays 1st item
    list.Add(innerCls)
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem=innerCls 'No effect
End Sub
```

How do I make **ComboBox1.SelectedItem** bind to [Class].InnerProperty correctly?
How do I set **ComboBox1.SelectedItem** manually?

Comment: You're also repeating `DisplayMember` twice, which I don't think is what you want; you probably want `ValueMember` in one of those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Databinding only works with Properties, not Fields.  I added the ComboBox ValueMember property, and I changed the DataBinding to use the SelectedValue property.

Here is a reworked example:

```
Class InnerClass
  Public Property InnerProperty As String
End Class

Class [Class]
  Public Property [Property] As String
  Public Property InnerClass As InnerClass
End Class

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)

  Dim cls As New [Class]
  Dim innerCls As New InnerClass

  Dim list As New BindingList(Of InnerClass)
  list.Add(New InnerClass With {.InnerProperty = "aaa"})
  list.Add(New InnerClass With {.InnerProperty = "bbb"})
  list.Add(New InnerClass With {.InnerProperty = "ccc"})
  cls.InnerClass = list(2)
  ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "InnerProperty"
  ComboBox1.ValueMember = "InnerProperty"
  ComboBox1.DataSource = list

  Dim bd As New Binding("SelectedValue", cls, "InnerClass.InnerProperty")
  ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(bd)
End Sub
```

On a side note, please avoid creating a class called "Class" and a Property called "Property".  Give them real names.

To use the class, you would have to use SelectedItem instead:

```
Dim bd As New Binding("SelectedItem", cls, "InnerClass")
```

Comment: I want to bind to cls.InnerClass, not cls.InnerClass.InnerProperty

Comment: @SimbarasheMukodzani Then change the binding property to use "SelectedItem".  See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set ComboBox1.SelectedItem manually?

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = Object
```

Which in your case is "bbb - bbb" I think, since you are using the the same thing for display and value members.  The ComboBox1.SelectedValue = "bbb" is easier to read and type.  Usually manipulating the Selected Value or Index is easier, or less error prone for me.  Like Ken White said though you need to express the valuemember to use it.

Comment: The ValueMember is the same as the DisplayMember,What i want is to have the SelectedItem be put in the cls.InnerClass when a user makes a change

Comment: Your code is confusing to me, but generally on the "build" of the combobox you'd pass in a value.  You need to have the "New" method in your class.  list.Add(New InnerClass("aaa") with a method in your InnerClass like:                                                  Public Sub New(sInnerProperty As String) MyBase.New()
Me.InnerProperty = sInnerProperty
End Sub